# Getting path of log4j.properties file from aplication.properties file into web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, log4j

I am working on a spring-mvc/maven application which is deployed on jboss through war file. I used log4j to insert logs into the database. Here is a snippet of my log4j.properties file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.com.ge.epay.web.controller=INFO
log4j.logger.com.ge=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR
log4j.logger.java.sql=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.mybatis=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.mchange=ERROR
```

I wanted to change the log level from ERROR to DEBUG without having to re-deploy the application after making changes in the log4j.properties.
So I kept the log4j.properties file outside the war and used Log4jConfigListener in my web.xml. Below is the snippet of my web.xml file.

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>file:/some path</param-value>  
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Time interval in millisecond after which the log4j properties will 
        be refreshed from the external file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>1200000</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

As you can see I am defining the path of log4j.properies file in my web.xml itself as log4jConfigLocation parameter.
I want to have this location to be defined in application.properties file or environment.properties file.

Is it possible to fetch the location from properties file and use it in web.xml?
Is it safe to keep log4j.properties file outside the war and read it from application?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your log properties tends to be read from classpath, so setting the location of your property file as classpath might be your solution

Comment: log4j.properties file is not inside the project. It is placed on some other location. Its path is mentioned in the web.xml

Answer (score 0):

@waquar I am very late. But Hopefully the answer will be useful for the beginners.

You can use the expression language to mention the path of the log4j file like below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:#{systemProperties['user.home']}/somepath/log4j.properties</param-value>  
</context-param>
```